# RecyclerView displays just one value

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I'm using the OpenWeatherApp, and wanted to display some content of the api callback in the RecyclerView, but sadly I'm getting only one value instead (as I hardcoded that) 15 values. Can somebody point where's the actual issue?

Here's the response when I'll print it in the console

```
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590148800
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590159600
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590170400
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590181200
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590192000
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590202800
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590213600
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590224400
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590235200
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590246000
2020-05-22 12:24:35.552 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590256800
2020-05-22 12:24:35.553 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590267600
2020-05-22 12:24:35.553 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590278400
2020-05-22 12:24:35.553 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590289200
2020-05-22 12:24:35.553 18727-18727/com.example.test I/System.out: 1590300000
```

And the value that I see in the TextView is same as the last print from the console

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    List<ModelClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Adapter123 adapter123 = new Adapter123();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recy);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter123);
        test();


    }

    private void test(){
        Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiCalls apiCalls = retrofit.create(ApiCalls.class);

        apiCalls.testCall("London","metric","XXX")
                .enqueue(new Callback<ModelClass>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ModelClass> call, Response<ModelClass> response) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.w(TAG, "onResponse: error "+response.code());
                        }
                        list = Collections.singletonList(response.body());
                        adapter123.set(list);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ModelClass> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onFailure: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n"+t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
   public class Adapter123 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter123.HolderTest> {
    List<ModelClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderTest onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        return new HolderTest(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderTest holder, int position) {
        ModelClass listClass = list.get(position);

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            holder.asd.setText(String.valueOf(listClass.getListClasses().get(i).getDt()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void set(List<ModelClass> listClasses){
        this.list = listClasses;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class HolderTest extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView asd;
        public HolderTest(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            asd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recy"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Collections.singletonList creates a list with only one element

Comment: Haven't know that, thank you. Actually I can't cast something like "list = response.body();" how I may solve that?